# wierd behaviour while copying address in string

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  int *p = (int *)malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
  char str1[20] ;
  char str2[20] ;
  sprintf(str1,"%20.20p",p);  
  sprintf(str2,"%20.20p",p);
  printf("%d\t%20.20s\n",strlen(str1),str1);
  printf("%d\t%20.20s\n",strlen(str2),str2);
  if(strcmp(str1,str2) == 0)
    printf("SAME\n");
  else
    printf("DIFFERENT\n");
  free(p);
  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
42  0x000000000000083bc0
22  0x000000000000083bc0
DIFFERENT
```

The string length always differ in each and every compiler I ran . Though the pointer was same every single time . Not sure why . Because the length is different the strings are also not matching.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are printing a `22` character string (`23` counting the trailing `\0`) into a pair of `20` character buffers. This means that the program is free to overwrite the end of your strings at any point, since that memory is not reserved. You will see even stranger results if you replace `%20.20s` with plain `%s` in your print statements. The fix is to declare `str1[23]; str2[23];` (don't forget the trailing `\0`), and don't restrict the print output: use plain `%s`.

You got off lucky in that your program prints an output without crashing. Not allocating enough memory can cause two problems:

1. You overwrite something important without realizing it.
2. Something else overwrites your data. This can cause things like your strings suddenly having a length of thousands of characters if the terminator is overwritten.

Comment: Boss what's the solution of this problem

Comment: Quoting myself, as I so often do: "The fix is to declare `str1[23]; str2[23];`."

Comment: @user3798283 The solution is to actually read and understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `sprintf(str1,"%20.20p",p);` will print more than 20 symbols into `str1`, so you have a buffer overflow in your code - the first `printf` prints to both `str1` and to a part of `str2`, and the second `printf` overwrites that part inside `str2`.

It actually prints `0x0000000000000173d010`, which is 23 symbols, including zero character at the end.